# I want my app to look the same on different devices?

Tags: android, eclipse

Now, the word Eclipse is much smaller on a 10.1" Tablet than on a Nexus1, for example. Or the distance between the button and the word Eclipse ist not the same on different devices. How can I Change it, that my app Looks the same on different devices?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnKlick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Klick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvhallo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:text="Eclipse"
    android:textSize="70sp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options you can try. The first is create 3 different layout folders: layout (already created), layout-sw600dp (for 7 in tablets), and layout-sw720dp (10.1 tablets).  Then put the same layout file in each of them and customize the appearance to suit your needs. Android will automatically select the layout based on the device. For more information go to : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

The other option is slightly more tricky. It, like the layout folder, requires you to create more folders. In this case you would create the folders: values-sw600dp and values-720 for 7in and 10in tablet respectively. Inside each of these folders you will have a dimens file where you can specify size for different layouts.

For Example:
for mobile, in values/dimens you can put

```
<dimen name="button_text_size">20sp</dimen>
```

and for 7in in tablet,in values-sw600dp/dimens you can put

```
<dimen name="button_text_size">24sp</dimen>
```

and for 10in in tablet,in values-sw600dp/dimens you can put

```
<dimen name="button_text_size">28sp</dimen>
```

Then in you layout file you can just call

```
android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
```

Android will automatically apply the correct size based on your devce. Hopefully this helps

Comment: +1 I would recommend the second option as perfect optimized way.